# I want to get values from this array but I m not able to select it accurately

Tags: reactjs

This is an image from console, as I have an `Array` and I want to select value of `name`,

[image]

I'm trying to do it as
`console.log(meetingConductingMembers.name)`

Then I don't get the value of this object but getting error undefined in console.
I can see that the Array is starting with some id but how to integrate it to get the actual value.

Comment: `meetingConductingMembers.name` ---> `meetingConductingMembers[0].name`

Comment: >  _I can see that the Array is starting with some id._ That is the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meetingConductingMembers` is an array with only one object, hence `index` as 0

```
console.log(meetingConductingMembers[0].name)
```

Answer (score 2):

`meetingConductingMembers` is an array so you have to write:

```
console.log(meetingConductingMembers[0].name)
```